# How can I use CASE function to Remove HIGHLIGHTED NULL to 0

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

```
SELECT E.employee_id AS "EMPLOYEE ID", E.first_name AS "FIRST NAME", E.salary AS "SALARY",
       L.state_province AS "STATE", L.city AS "CITY",
       D.department_name AS "DEPARTMENT NAME"

FROM employees E Inner JOIN departments D
ON E.department_id = D.department_id
INNER JOIN locations L
ON D.location_id = L.location_id
```

[image]

Comment: `COALESCE( column, 'default value')` is used to replace NULLs with a default

Comment: I want to use CASE FUNCTION

Comment: Why would you want to replace a state name with `'0'`?

Comment: I am just practicing so... not focusing on the replaced value focusing on how can i replace it

Comment: Please include content, not pictures of content in your questions.

Comment: `COALESCE( column, 'default value')` is a shortcut for `CASE WHEN column IS NULL THEN 'default value' ELSE column END`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace:

```
L.state_province AS "STATE"
```

By:

```
case when L.state_province is null then '0' else L.state_province end AS "STATE"
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use case then you can do :

```
SELECT 
     E.employee_id AS "EMPLOYEE ID", 
     E.first_name AS "FIRST NAME", 
     E.salary AS "SALARY",
     (CASE WHEN  L.state_province IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE  L.state_province END) AS "STATE", 
     L.city AS "CITY",
     D.department_name AS "DEPARTMENT NAME"
FROM employees E
Inner JOIN departments D ON E.department_id = D.department_id
INNER JOIN locations L ON D.location_id = L.location_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your SELECT statement, you could wrap your columns with the ISNULL() function.

Example below:-

```
SELECT E.employee_id AS "EMPLOYEE ID", E.first_name AS "FIRST NAME", E.salary AS "SALARY",
   ISNULL(L.state_province,'0') AS "STATE", L.city AS "CITY",
   D.department_name AS "DEPARTMENT NAME"
```

Alternatively you could use a CASE statement, such as:

```
SELECT E.employee_id AS "EMPLOYEE ID", E.first_name AS "FIRST NAME", E.salary AS "SALARY",
   CASE WHEN L.state_province IS NULL then '0' ELSE L.state_province END AS "STATE", L.city AS "CITY",
   D.department_name AS "DEPARTMENT NAME"
```